# How do I include a php.ini file in another php.ini file?

Tags: php, configuration

How do I include a php.ini file in another php.ini file?

Comment: I'm interested how RHEL/Fedora accomplishes the /etc/php.d/* include.  Did they patch PHP to make this possible?

Comment: @gahooa that's the question that I had leading me here. Did you ever learn how they accomplish the /etc/php.d/* include?

Comment: see the accepted answer below, this answers your question too. U can also do php -i (phpinfo() ) and see how the php was built

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think you can "include" .ini files from the main php.ini file.

One possible solution, though, might be to use this option on the configure line, when compiling PHP:

```
--with-config-file-scan-dir=PATH
    Set the path where to scan for configuration files
```

If this option is used at compile-time, PHP will look for every .ini file in this directory, in addition to the "normal" *php.ini* file.

I suppose this is what is used by [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), for instance, which uses a different .ini file for each downloaded extension, instead of modifying *php.ini*.

The path to the *php.ini* file is being defined with this option, on the configure line:

```
--with-config-file-path=PATH
    Set the path in which to look for php.ini [PREFIX/lib]
```

Still, it probably means you'll have to re-compile PHP -- which is not that hard, btw -- the hardest part being to get the dependencies you need.

And, here is a post on the internals@ mailling-list that says the same thing as I do: *[config files and `PHP_CONFIG_FILE_SCAN_DIR`](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=122971082314313&w=2)*

Comment: In addition to compile time setting, there is also an environment variable `PHPRC` which makes possible to change default `php.ini` (and possible other ini files) directory.

Comment: When you say on the configure line, what does that mean? Is that a file somewhere?

Comment: Note that Debian-packaged PHP builds are configured to scan a web-server-specific directory at startup for additional config files.  Any `*.ini` file found in the directory is treated as if it were part of `php.ini`.  It is likely Debian-derived distros such as Ubuntu also do this.  Example directory: `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/`  Reference: `/usr/share/doc/php7.4-common/README.Debian.gz`

Answer (score 11):

One can also define the path in `~/.bashrc`

```
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/usr/local/lib/php.d
```

Comment: wouldn’t it only work in CLI and not httpd

Answer (score 9):

I installed [Memcached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) for php and wasn't sure how to make sure that its ini was included in my *php.ini* file, but as it turns out, it automatically is. You can validate what is being loaded by running `php --ini`.

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/local/etc/php5
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/local/var/db/php5
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/local/var/db/php5/memcached.ini
```

Comment: it sounds like config file path returned by "php --ini" maybe not the same as returned from web  page (<?php phpinfo(); ?>) .

Answer (score 5):

It seems you cannot include one ini file into another so it gets referenced and loaded. But you can set `php` up to load several files by telling it which folders to look into.

When using a [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) setup (possibly in FPM, too, though I don't know that for sure) you can export environment variables from within the PHP wrapper.

There you could do:

```
export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d:/var/www/mydomain.net/etc
```

`/var/www/mydomain.net/etc` is just an example. It's the folder where you put your additional ini files into. It seems this can be a `:` separated list.

Use a `phpinfo.php` (file called arbitrarily containing only `<?php phpinfo();`), open the corresponding URL in your browser and check the list of directories that are parsed and the list of files that get loaded in the top area of it.

`/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d` should always be included (I guess because it was compiled into the PHP executable) and possibly not really be needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Read online pages:

[The configuration file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

> SUMMARY: The configuration file
> (php.ini) is read when PHP starts up.
> For the server module versions of PHP,
> this happens only once when the web
> server is started. For the CGI and CLI
> version, it happens on every
> invocation.

[.user.ini files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

> SUMMARY: In addition to the main
> php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files
> in each directory, starting with the
> directory of the requested PHP file,
> and working its way up to the current
> document root (as set in
> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). Only INI
> settings with the modes PHP_INI_PERDIR
> and PHP_INI_USER will be recognized in
> .user.ini-style INI files.

Comment: I read those before posting, says nothing about including whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to simulate it making use of the [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function.  But as the "man page" indicates, not all ini options can be changed using ini_set.  It's definitely a useful function, though.