# Is possible to split PHP configuration file php.ini?

Tags: php, include, configuration-files

Anyone working with php knows that php.ini is a big file that may cause headaches when you need to change over ssh.

For example I can change nginx.conf using `include` directive to load all of the files under sites-enabled dir into the main nginx.conf.

So my question is straightforward: It's possible to do the same thing with php.ini ?

Comment: Sounds like a http://serverfault.com question, to be completely honest.

Comment: Are you not using `vi` because its pretty easy if you do a `:/THE_PHP_SETTING` where `THE_PHP_SETTING` is your setting like `include_path` or what have you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your PHP installation is setup to scan for .ini files you can drop several of them in a folder. If you installed PHP through the Ubuntu repos, it should already be configured this way.

My `phpinfo()` (note: The additional ini files are the result of installing php extensions from the repos and won't be included with PHP):

[image: phpinfo with ini sections highlighted]

The setting for this directory is a compile-time option:

```
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
```

You can also set an environment variable through Apache:

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /php/custom/scan/directory
```

[More info @ ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/224685/php-ini-disable-scan-this-dir-for-additional-ini-files)

Comment: You can add serveral directories through the environment variable, too, it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41394568/805284