# PHP with PGSQL on Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, php-java-bridge, php-pgsql

I need to execute a php file on apache tomcat server that needs to access postgresql database.  The server is Centos Linux. I have apache tomcat 7 , php , postgresql and php-potgresql installed.

```
$ cat /etc/php.d/pgsql.ini  [gives the following]
; Enable pgsql extension module
extension=pgsql.so
```

However on loading the required page on a browser, i get the fowllowing error:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /home/criminfo/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/webapps/JavaBridgeTemplate621/hybrid.php on line 4

type Exception report

message java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /home/criminfo/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/webapps/JavaBridgeTemplate621/hybrid.php on line 4

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Any directions on how to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether the additional modules have been loaded correctly by calling `phpinfo();`? There may be a wrong path setting or the module file itself maybe missing.

Comment: @Michael Additional Modules in phpinfo() just has "readline". How can I load the module?

Comment: You have to make sure, that you ini file is loaded correctly (you already named `/etc/php.d/pgsql.ini`). There is another section in the `phpinfo()` which has information about the loaded ini files ("Additional .ini files parsed"). If you file is not listed there, you maybe have to change your compile settings (see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391808/how-do-i-include-a-php-ini-file-in-another-php-ini-file))

Comment: Do `# service daemon-name reload`. If it were apache I would do `# service httpd reload`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto - does'nt help. same error

Comment: @Michael pgsql.ini is'nt present in "Additional .ini files parsed". But am not really clear on how to change the compile settings to fix it. please help...

Comment: Please try the code in the example I linked in my second comment. BTW: Why are you using a Tomcat server to deliver PHP?

Comment: @Michael no specific reason.. what wouldd be a better alternative?

Comment: The "default" http server project http://httpd.apache.org/ Tomcat is usually used for java applications whereas the http server is the most common web server for PHP I think.