# Apache - CentOS - "Scan this dir for additional .ini files"

Tags: php, apache, centos6, ini, server

Is there a way to set a location for apache to read custom php.inis from? Currently it says "`Scan this dir for additional .ini files`" as "`(none)`"

The environment is CentoOS 6, Apache 2, and PHP running via DSO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a php.ini file in another php.ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391808/how-do-i-include-a-php-ini-file-in-another-php-ini-file)

Answer (score -1):

[Scan directories](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file.scan) for `.ini` files is configured at compiled time via `--with-config-file-scan-dir` option.

However for later versions of PHP from `v5.2.0` you can overwrite it at run time by setting `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` environment variable.

You can employ [SetEnv directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) within context of a server config, virtual host, directory or `.htaccess` file to update this value.

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR /usr/local/opt/php-extras
```

Comment: This question was 5-6 years old and duplicated at least 3 times.

Comment: I checked the question to linked to and there are differences there.  First this question appears before the others. It asks specifically about *configuring the scan directories in Apache*. You don't think both question to be same, do you?