# how to install PHP PDO SQL Server driver on Arch Linux?

Tags: php, sql-server, archlinux

I'm aware that this question have already been asked but I think my situation is a bit similar to them because my OS is Arch Linux, I have `mssql-server` and `mssql-tools` installed and perfectly running, and for PHP PDO I have installed packages like `msodbcsql` and `unixodbc`.

now the weird point is when I run `php -a` on my Arch terminal and then run : `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()) ;` the result is :

```
(
    [0] => sqlsrv
)
```

, which means it's successfully installed, but when I do the same command on my localhost with IDE the result is `Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => pgsql [2] => sqlite )` .
could anybody help me with that?

Comment: Is your IDE and terminal using different `php.ini` files? Have you closed, and re-opened your IDE since you installed the drivers?

Comment: @Larnu tnx, just realized yes, they are different, shall I just replace them?

Comment: You *can*, or you can update the `php.ini` file your IDE is using to add the relevant drivers.

Comment: @Larnu but the point is one of the php.ini files only includes sqlsrv , is there a way to just add that sqlsrv to my IDE php.ini ? because I need mysql too

Comment: Which is why I recommended you update the `php.ini` file your IDE is using, not copy over it; they are clearly configured differently.

Comment: @Larnu you mean something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391808/how-do-i-include-a-php-ini-file-in-another-php-ini-file

Comment: No, I mean edit your `php.ini` file your IDE is using and install the SQL Server drivers. Do the steps you did for your terminal, for your IDE...

Comment: @Larnu well that's the problem, how can I force the packages to install drivers on my opt/lampp/etc/php.ini file?

Comment: Follow the documentation: [Install the SQL Server Driver for PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php)

Comment: @Larnu none of them is for arch, shall I just download one of them like ubuntu?

Comment: Because it's not supported on Arch. Neither are the tools you list above, but you've installed those.

Comment: @Larnu so what is your advice? is there a way to just manually copy and paste some codes?